# what is the difference between Logical Keyboard and Physical Keyboard classes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, input, focus

I am using KeyBoardListener to listen key events but there is confusion about logical keyboard keys and physical keyboard keys. Kindly explain it in simple terms. I am beginner.

Comment: [PhysicalKeyboard](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/PhysicalKeyboardKey-class.html), [LogicalKeyboard](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/LogicalKeyboardKey-class.html). You shouldn't post questions, that can be easily answered by google :)

Answer (score 0):

From the standpoint of the `KeyBoardListener`, there's no difference between the two - The event handling will be exactly the same.

From your standpoint a logical keyboard is just one that's shown on your device's screen, as opposed to a physical keyboard that sits on your desk/laptop.

But again, your app doesn't care if the keyboard is physical or virtual when it comes to handling events.